# Как обратиться к дочернему компоненту во Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть компонент для ввода даты по маске. При вводе даты посылается событие с параметром 1 или 0 в зависимости от валидности введённой даты. Появилась потребность сделать компонент из нескольких вышеописанных компонентов, каким образом можно проверить, что все даты заполнены и валидны если события поступают асинхронно?
P.S. компоненты для ввода даты создаются в цикле т.к. нет возможности проверить от какого дочернего компонента пришло событие.

```
// отправка события при вводе очередного значения в input
var isValid = checkValid();
this.$emit('valid', isValid);

// обработка события в родительском компоненте в функции someFunc
<input-date v-on:valid="someFunc"></input-date>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [`ref`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-amp-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Также его можно использовать совместно с [`nextTick`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick), чтобы массив `$refs` был заполнен.

Comment: спасибо, выручили